# How can I earn from the internet?

Tags: google-adsense, affiliate

I have done some searches on the best ways to start earning from the internet, But I found it's very interlaced and found many controversy.
Some say affiliate earns good, some say no and says it's difficult to compete, same goes for adsense.

Is it possible to really earn valuable money from the internet or it's too difficult ?
Note, My native tongue is Arabic, So I will be targeting Arabic speakers if I start, so it would be better if the answer is focused for Arabic market.